# Генератор случайных целых чисел не выдаёт значение нижней границы диапазона, если оно отрицательное. Как исправить?

Tags: java, случайные-числа

**Задача:** сгенерировать случайное число из диапазона [-15;10] (включительно). То есть -15 и 10 тоже могут выдаваться в качестве случайного значения.

Пишу на Java такой код:

```
// границы диапазона
int bottomLimit = -15;
int topLimit = 10;

// генерация
int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * (topLimit + 1 - bottomLimit) + bottomLimit);

// вывод
System.out.println(randomNumber);
```

Действительно, `randomNumber` при каждом вызове принимает значения то -13, то 0, то 9, в общем из заданного диапазона [-15;10].

**Проблема:** в качестве случайного значения ни разу не выпадает нижняя граница, то есть -15.

Я это проверил в цикле.

```
// границы диапазона
int bottomLimit = -15;
int topLimit = 10;
boolean isBottomLimit = false;
boolean isTopLimit = false;

/*
 * запускаю генератор 100 000 раз
 * Если в качестве значения randomNumber хоть раз выпадет значение bottomLimit, 
 * то isBottomLimit присваиваем true, которое изначально false. 
 * Аналогично для isTopLimit.
 */
for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++) {
    int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * (topLimit + 1 - bottomLimit) + bottomLimit);
    System.out.print(randomNumber + " ");
    if (randomNumber == bottomLimit) {
        isBottomLimit = true;
    }
    if (randomNumber == topLimit) {
        isTopLimit = true;
    }
}
System.out.println("\nСгенерировано ли хоть раз -15: " + isBottomLimit); // false
System.out.println("Сгенерировано ли хоть раз 10: " + isTopLimit); // true
```

В итоге верхняя граница `topLimit` диапазона хоть раз, но генерируется.
А нижняя `bottomLimit`, какое большое бы число проверок не проводилось, не генерируется.

**Что изменить в коде, чтобы и нижняя граница тоже «участвовала» в качестве значения случайного числа из диапазона?**

P. S.
Кстати, если нижняя граница — не отрицательное число, то рандомное число может спокойно принять, как значение и нижней границы диапазона, так и верхней.

```
int bottomLimit = 5; // нижняя граница диапазона — не отрицательное число
int topLimit = 10;
boolean isBottomLimit = false;
boolean isTopLimit = false;

for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++) {
    int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * (topLimit + 1 - bottomLimit) + bottomLimit);
    System.out.print(randomNumber + " ");
    if (randomNumber == bottomLimit) {
        isBottomLimit = true;
    }
    if (randomNumber == topLimit) {
        isTopLimit = true;
    }
}
System.out.println("\nСгенерировано ли хоть раз 5: " + isBottomLimit); // true
System.out.println("Сгенерировано ли хоть раз 10: " + isTopLimit); // true
```

Comment: Наводящий вопрос - `Math.random() * (topLimit + 1 - bottomLimit) + bottomLimit` - зачем у вас тут `+1` ?

Comment: Чтобы захватывать верхнюю границу. Без единицы в этом месте не генерируется в качестве случайного ни верхняя, ни нижняя граница.

Comment: Дока по Java утверждает, что диапазон вот такой - `(0.0 <= Math.random() < 1.0`. Соответственно, нижнее генерировать будет, а верхнее "почти".

Comment: Про это и вопрос. Если `Math.random()` может генерировать значение `0.0`, то почему он его не генерирует в приведённом примере с нижней отрицательной границей.

Если `Math.random()` выкидывает `0`, значит `randomNumber` должен равняться `-15`.

```int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * (topLimit + 1 - bottomLimit) + bottomLimit);```
← 
```int randomNumber = (int) (0.0 * (topLimit + 1 - bottomLimit) + bottomLimit);```
← 
```int randomNumber = (int) (0.0 + bottomLimit);``` — то есть randomNumber = bottomLimit

Но этого не происходит

Comment: `Если Math.random() может генерировать значение 0.0, то почему он его не генерирует в приведённом примере с нижней отрицательной границей` - все просто, 100000 проверок слишком мало. Если у вас в Джаве 32-битные числа с точкой, то в диапазоне от 0 до 1 примерно 1 млдр возможных чисел. Шансов что вам повезет встретить строго 0 - почти нет. А вот как именно это все к int приводится (округляется или отбрасывается) - не знаю.

Comment: У меня есть подозрени что в джаве округление к нулю

Comment: При приведении `double` к `int` отбрасывается дробная часть. Если `Math.random` сгенерирует число, близкое к нулю, то получится что-то вроде `(int) (0.01 - 15)` => `(int) (-14.99)` => `-14`. По этой же причине значение `0` в вашем генераторе будет выпадать в 2 раза чаще.

Comment: `int randomNumber = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (topLimit + 1 - bottomLimit)) + bottomLimit;`. Общее правило: если вам нужно предсказуемое приведение вещественного числа используйте `Math.floor`, `Math.ceil` или `Math.round`. Только после них можно вызывать приведение.

Comment: Math.floor должен помочь, да, он округляет вниз. Но зачем все эти сложности, если можно сразу [сгенерировать целое число](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1437698), а не дробное.

Comment: @Vadik, я показал как поправить текущий код, не более.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш генератор псевдослучайных чисел выдает значение `0` в 2 раза чаще, чем остальные значения, это нехорошо.

Если вы хотите генерировать целочисленные значения, то воспользуйтесь целочисленным генератором [`nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#nextInt()) у класса [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html) (или [`SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/SecureRandom.html)):

```java
Random random = new SecureRandom();
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(top - bottom + 1) + bottom;
System.out.println(randomNumber);
```

Для отрезка от -5 до 5 результаты для 1 млн. чисел такие:

```
-5  =>  90984
-4  =>  90888
-3  =>  91141
-2  =>  90878
-1  =>  90720
0   =>  90855
1   =>  91062
2   =>  90676
3   =>  90659
4   =>  91019
5   =>  91118
```

Answer (score -1):

Нашёл решение. Нужно в формулу генерации случайного числа вставить не значение нижней границы, а значение нижней границы, уменьшенной на единицу.
Причём это нужно делать только тогда, когда нижняя граница отрицательная.

```
// Границы диапазона [-15;10] (оба включительно)
int bottomLimit = -15;
int topLimit = 10;
boolean isBottomLimit = false;
boolean isTopLimit = false;

/*
 * Если нижняя граница диапазона меньше нуля, 
 * уменьшаем нижнюю границу на единицу, 
 * иначе оставляем значение нижней границы как есть
 */
int editedBottomLimit = bottomLimit < 0 ? bottomLimit - 1 : bottomLimit;

/*
 * При 100 000 проверок хоть раз в качестве случайного числа
 * сгенерируется и нижняя граница, и верхняя
 */
for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++) {
    int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * (topLimit + 1 - editedBottomLimit) + editedBottomLimit);
    System.out.print(randomNumber + " ");
    if (randomNumber == bottomLimit) {
        isBottomLimit = true;
    }
    if (randomNumber == topLimit) {
        isTopLimit = true;
    }
}
System.out.println("\nСгенерировано ли хоть раз " + bottomLimit + ": " + isBottomLimit); // true
System.out.println("Сгенерировано ли хоть раз " + topLimit + ": " + isTopLimit); // true
```

Comment: Ужасное решение.

Comment: Это плохой генератор, не используйте его. При отрицательных `bottomLimit` генератор будет выдавать значение `0` в два раза чаще, чем другие числа. Число `0` выпадает с вероятностью 7.4%, а любое другое число — с вероятностью 3.7%.